# Creating dummy QOpenGLWidget affects QPainter performance in Qt 5.8 and 5.9 on MacOS

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, qpainter

I found that if I (somewhere in my widget before doing any QPainter drawing) run the following code:

```
if (!QOpenGLContext::currentContext())
{
  QOpenGLWidget * open_gl_w = new QOpenGLWidget(this);

  QSurfaceFormat format;
  format.setSamples(5);
  open_gl_w->setFormat(format);
  open_gl_w->setUpdateBehavior(QOpenGLWidget::PartialUpdate);

  open_gl_w->setGeometry(0, 0, 20, 20);
  open_gl_w->show();

  delete open_gl_w;
}
```

then somehow following drawing performance of QPainter (not OpenGL, just normal) is dramatically increased. Like it draws relatively complex scene several times faster than without such strange initialization of OpenGL engine.

I should add that it only happens once: next time I run the code, currentContext() returns true.

Certainly I like the result, but also I'd like to know what's going on.

Comment: What does [`QWidget::paintEngine()->type()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintengine.html#type) return with and without the OpenGL code?

Comment: well, for that I get this: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called, just before the exception.

Comment: if I call QPainter::paintEngine()->type() for the painter, I get "Raster" for QWidget and "OpenGL2" for QOpenGLWidget, which is what I'd expect.